# Using client-only routes with page templates coming from Contentful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system, gatsby

#### Goal

I am looking to use client-only routes for content under a certain URL (`/dashboard`). Some of this content will be coming from Contentful and using a page template. An example of this route would be `{MYDOMAIN}/dashboard/{SLUG_FROM_CONTENTFUL}`. The purpose of this is to ensure projects I have worked on at an agency are not able to be crawled/accessed and are only visible to 'employers' once logged in.

#### What I have tried

My pages are generated via `gatsby-node.js`. The way of adding authentication/client-only routes has been taken from [this example](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/authentication-tutorial). Now the basics of it have been setup and working fine, from what I can tell. But the private routes seem to only work in the following cases:

If I'm logged in and navigate to `/dashboard`

- I'm shown `Profile.js`

If I an not logged in and go to `/dashboard`

- I'm shown `Login.js`

So that all seems to be fine. The issue comes about when I go to `/dashboard/url-from-contentful` and I am not logged in. I am served the page instead of being sent to `/dashboard/login`.

```js
exports.createPages = async ({graphql, actions}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    
    const { data } = await graphql(`
        query {
            agency: allContentfulAgency {
                edges {
                    node {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `);
    data.agency.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
            path: `dashboard/${node.slug}`,
            component: path.resolve("src/templates/agency-template.js"),
            context: {
                slug: node.slug,
            },
        });
    });
}

exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    
    if(page.path.match(/^\/dashboard/)) {
        page.matchPath = "/dashboard/*";
        
        createPage(page);
    }
};
```

My `auth.js` is setup (the username and password are basic as I am still only developing this locally):

```js
export const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined";

export const getUser = () =>
  isBrowser() && window.localStorage.getItem("gatsbyUser")
    ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("gatsbyUser"))
    : {};

const setUser = (user) =>
  window.localStorage.setItem("gatsbyUser", JSON.stringify(user));

export const handleLogin = ({ username, password }) => {
  if (username === `john` && password === `pass`) {
    return setUser({
      username: `john`,
      name: `Johnny`,
      email: `johnny@example.org`,
    });
  }

  return false;
};

export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  const user = getUser();

  return !!user.username;
};

export const logout = (callback) => {
  setUser({});
  call
};
```

`PrivateRoute.js` is setup the following way:

```js
import React from "react";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import { isLoggedIn } from "../services/auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/dashboard/login`) {
    navigate("/dashboard/login");
    return null;
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

`dashboard.js` has the following. The line `<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard/url-from-contentful" component={Agency} />`, I have tried a couple of things here - Statically typing the route and using the `exact` prop, using route parameters such as `/:id`, `/:path`, `/:slug` :

```js
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Profile from "../components/Profile";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import PrivateRoute from "../components/PrivateRoute";
import Agency from "../templates/agency-template";

const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Router>
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard/url-from-contentful" component={Agency} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" />
      <Login path="/dashboard/login" />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
);

export default App;
```

And finally `agency-template.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby";
import styled from "styled-components";
import SEO from "../components/SEO";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Gallery from "../components/Gallery";
import GeneralContent from "../components/GeneralContent/GeneralContent";

const agencyTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  const {
    name,
    excerpt,
    richDescription,
    richDescription: { raw },
    images,
    technology,
    website,
  } = data.agency;

  const [mainImage, ...projectImages] = images;

  return (
    <>
      <SEO title={name} description={excerpt} />
      <Layout>
        <div className="container__body">
          <GeneralContent title={name} />
          <Gallery mainImage={mainImage} />

          <GeneralContent title="Project Details" content={richDescription} />
          <div className="standard__images">
            <Gallery projectImages={projectImages} />
          </div>
          <ViewWebsite>
            <Link className="btn" to={website}>
              View the website
            </Link>
          </ViewWebsite>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query ($slug: String!) {
    agency: contentfulAgency(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      name
      excerpt
      technology
      website
      images {
        description
        gatsbyImageData(
          layout: FULL_WIDTH
          placeholder: TRACED_SVG
          formats: [AUTO, WEBP]
          quality: 90
        )
      }
      richDescription {
        raw
      }
    }
  }
`;
export default agencyTemplate;
```

I assume that gating content from a CMS is possible with Gatsby but I might be wrong given it is an SSG. I may be misunderstanding the fundamentals of client-only. The concepts in React and using Gatsby are still very new to me so any help or guidance in achieving the goal would be appreciated.

#### What I ended up doing

So the answer I marked was the one that 'got the ball rolling'. The explanation of what was happening with state and requiring either `useContext` or redux helped me understand where I was going wrong.

Also, the suggestion to use web tokens prompted me to find more information on using Auth0 with the application.

Once I had got out of the mindset of creating pages using Gatsby (Through a template, via `gatsby-node.s`), and instead doing it in a 'React way' (I know Gatsby is built with React) by handling the routing and GraphQL it became clearer. Along with the authentication, all I ended up doing was creating a new `<Agency />` component and feeding the data from GraphQL into it and updating the path with my `map()`.

```js
return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <DashboardArea path="/dashboard/" user={user} />
        {agencyData.map(({ node }, index) =>
          node.slug ? (
            <Agency key={index} data={node} path={`/dashboard/${node.slug}`} />
          ) : null
        )}
      </Router>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in your PrivateRoute component, you're using the isLoggedIn check incorrectly. importing and using isLoggedIn from auth.js will run only initially and will not act as a listner. What you can do is that store the value of isLoggedin in global state variable like(useContext or redux) and make a custom hook to check for the login state. Secondly avoid accessing localStorage directly, instead use the global state managment (useContext, redux) or local state managment (useState, this.state).
Note: that when ever you go to a route by directly pasting url in browser, it always refreshes the page and all your stored state is reinitialized. This may be the reason why you may be experiencing this issue. The browser does not know that you had been previously logged in and therefore it always validates once your application is mounted. What you can do is that you can store isLoggedIn state in browser's localstore. Personally I like to use redux-persist for that.

```
export const useGetUser = () => { //add use infront to make a custom hook
  return useSelector(state => state.gatsByUser) // access user info from redux store
};


export const handleLogin = ({ username, password }) => {
  //suggestion: don't validate password on client side or simply don't use password, 
  //instead use tokens for validation on client side

  if (username === `john` && password === `pass`) {
    dispatch(setUserInfo({
      username: `john`,
      name: `Johnny`,
      email: `johnny@example.org`,
      isLoggedIn: true,
    }));
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};


// adding 'use' infront to make it a custom hook
export const useIsLoggedIn = () => {
  //this will act as a listner when ever the state changes
  return useSelector(state => state.gatsByUser?.isLoggedIn ?? false);
};

export const logout = (callback) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // redux
  dispatch(clearUserInfo());
};
```

Now in private route do

```
import React from "react";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import { useIsLoggedIn } from "../services/auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  const isLoggedIn = useIsLoggedIn();

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return navigate("/dashboard/login");
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're server-side rendering `dashboard/[url]` in `gatsby-node.js/createPages()`? IIRC those routes will have higher precedence than dynamic routes (which you specify with @reach/router in dashboard.js).

Plus, the content of those routes are currently publicly available. If you want to keep them truly private, you should query Contentful graphql API directly on the client side (via `fetch()` or use apollo client, urql, etc.), instead of relying on Gatsby's graphql server.

I would do the follows:

- Removing the `dashboard/[url]` portion in your gatsby-node.js
- Configure your web host so that all routes matches '/dashboard/*' will redirect to '/dashboard'

If you happen to host your static site on Netlify, you'd create a _redirects with this, assuming you configure Gatsby to create nice url:

```
# /static/_redirect

/dashboard/*   /dashboard   200
```

---

A possible simpler way that match your current setup is gating content at web host level. You can configure nginx to protect `/dasboard/*` with basic auth. However maintaining/updating password is a pain & modern hosting solution don't really allow user to configure that.

Netlify offers its own authentication solution that you could look into.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue earlier and I couldn't get exact functionality with Private Routes.

In my case, I created two separate Layouts for Public and Private Routes and built the authentication to Private Layout. Logged-in user data were linked to a redux store (First I used Context, then moved to Redux). In Private routes with the Private Layout, it redirected the guest users to the Login page and redirected them to the same page after login.

Private layout is something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const PrivateLayout = ({children}) => {
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.user.isLoggedIn);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            // redirect the user to login page.
            // I'm sending the current page's URL as the redirect URL
            // so that I can take the user back to this page after logging in.
        }
    }, [isLoggedIn])

    if (!isLoggedIn) return null;

    return <>
        {...header}
        {children}
        {...footer}
    </>
}

export default PrivateLayout;
```

Not sure if this workaround suits you. If it does, I can give you more info.